# Evitar que se dupliquen datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Como puedo evitar que se dupliquen registros en la base de datos. Lo que trato de hacer es primeramente una consulta del registro. A continuación muestro el código.

```
/**
 * Representa el data de los gastos
 * almacenados en la base de datos
 */
require 'DatabaseConnection.php';

class Notas
{


// Nombre de la tabla asociada a esta clase
const TABLE_NAME = "remisiones";

const RUTA = "ruta";

const VENDEDOR = "vendedor";

const FECHAOPERACION = "fechaOperacion";

const FECHAREGISTRO = "fechaRegistro";

const CODIGOCLT = "codigoClt";

const CODIGOPRD = "codigoPrd";

const PRECIO = "precio";

const IVA = "IVA";

const CANTIDAD = "cantidad";

const TOTALNOTA = "totalNota";

const DETALLE = "detalle";

function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * Obtiene todos los gastos de la base de datos
 * @return array|bool Arreglo con todos los gastos o false en caso de error
 */
public static function getAll()
{
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLE_NAME;
    try {
        // Preparar sentencia
        $comando = DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
        // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
        $comando->execute();

        return $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static function insertRow($object)
{
    try {

        $pdo = DatabaseConnection::getInstance()->getDb();

       $bsuqueda = "SELECT count (*) as fechaRegistro FROM " . self::TABLE_NAME . " WHERE " . self::FECHAREGISTRO . "=?" ;
       $query = $pdo ->prepare($bsuqueda);
       $query ->bindParam(1, $fechaRegistro);
       $query -> execute();
       echo "num_rows = ".$query->fetchColumn."\n";

        if ($query->fetchColumn() == 0)
       {

         // Sentencia INSERT
        $comando = "INSERT INTO " . self::TABLE_NAME . " ( " .
            self::RUTA . "," .
            self::VENDEDOR . "," .
            self::FECHAOPERACION . "," .
            self::FECHAREGISTRO . "," .
    self::CODIGOCLT . "," .
    self::CODIGOPRD . "," .
    self::PRECIO . "," .
    self::IVA . "," .
    self::CANTIDAD . "," .
    self::TOTALNOTA . "," .
            self::DETALLE . ")".

            " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        // Preparar la sentencia
        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare($comando);

        $sentencia->bindParam(1, $ruta);
        $sentencia->bindParam(2, $vendedor);
        $sentencia->bindParam(3, $fechaOperacion);
        $sentencia->bindParam(4, $fechaRegistro);
    $sentencia->bindParam(5, $codigoClt);
    $sentencia->bindParam(6, $codigoPrd);
    $sentencia->bindParam(7, $precio);
    $sentencia->bindParam(8, $IVA);
    $sentencia->bindParam(9, $cantidad);
    $sentencia->bindParam(10,$totalNota);
        $sentencia->bindParam(11,$detalle);

       /*$ruta = $object[self::RUTA];
        $vendedor = $object[self::VENDEDOR];
        $fechaOperacion = $object[self::FECHAOPERACION];
        $fechaRegistro = $object[self::FECHAREGISTRO];
    $codigoClt = $object[self::CODIGOCLT];
    $codigoPrd = $object[self::CODIGOPRD];
    $precio = $object[self::PRECIO];            
    $IVA = $object[self::IVA];
    $cantidad = $object[self::CANTIDAD];
    $totalNota = $object[self::TOTALNOTA];
        $detalle = $object[self::DETALLE];*/

      $ruta = "1";
        $vendedor = "Prueba";
        $fechaOperacion = "2016-03-08";
        $fechaRegistro = "2035-12-10 13:46:05";
    $codigoClt = "1";
    $codigoPrd = "1";
    $precio = "9.41";            
    $IVA = "16";
    $cantidad = "35";
    $totalNota = "329.35";
        $detalle ="n";


        $sentencia->execute();

        // Retornar en el ultimo id insertado
        return $pdo->lastInsertId();
      }else
        {

          echo ("No se puede crear un registro ya exitente");

         }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Al momento de ejecutar, se sigue insertando el campo a pesar de que ya existe.

Comment: Hola Ismael, esto es de php pero porque el tag android? Lo eliminé, comentame si me equivoco, saludos.

Comment: Mejor utiliza el mysql_num_rows, un ejemplo asi. <?php $enlace = mysql_connect("localhost", "usuario_mysql", "contraseña_mysql");
mysql_select_db("basedatos", $enlace); $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla1", $enlace);
$número_filas = mysql_num_rows($resultado); echo "$número_filas Filas\n"; ?>

Comment: Mira esto ...., te puede ayuda mucho al respecto, usa mysql_num_rows
<?php
$enlace = mysql_connect("localhost", "usuario_mysql", "contraseña_mysql");
mysql_select_db("basedatos", $enlace);
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla1", $enlace);
$número_filas = mysql_num_rows($resultado);
echo "$número_filas Filas\n";
?>

Comment: Lo pude resolver amigos gracias.

Comment: @IsmaelRodriguez podrías indicar cómo lo has resuelto y auto responder la pregunta? Así si alguien tiene el mismo problema va a poder verlo. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor es que la columna o combinacion que no se puede repetir la definas en un indice único

```
create table ........

unique ( columna )
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera muy sencilla de lograr eso.

Tienes que declarar en tu base de datos ciertas restricciones en los campos que lo requieras.

En tu caso bastaría con definir el campo "UNIQUE".

Al querer insertar un dao igual te arrojará una excepción, únicamente tienes que controlarla.